# TeamCity fails to trigger on wildcard-specified branch

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have the following setup in TeamCity:

Build Configuration Settings -> Version Control Settings -> VCS Root:

- Default branch: remote-run/my-feature
- Branch specification: remote-run/my-feature

This triggers perfectly when getting the commits from Github from remote-run/my-feature branch, but when I try to have it generic (all branches pushed on remote-run) like this:

- Default branch: remote-run/* OR refs/heads/remote-run/* OR +:refs/heads/remote-run/* OR -:refs/heads/remote-run/*
- Branch specification: remote-run/* OR refs/heads/remote-run/* OR +:refs/heads/remote-run/* OR           -:refs/heads/remote-run/*

nothing is being triggered.

Does anyone knows what branch specs is need in order to trigger when pushing to `remote-run/ANYTHING_HERE`?

Thanks,
Ionut

As a matter of fact, it fails connecting to the Github repo if I specify anything like:

`-:refs/heads/*/pull` or `-:refs/heads/*/merge` or `+:refs/heads/*/pull` or `+:refs/heads/*/merge` in the **Branch Specification** even though I have valid Pull Requests present in my Github repo.

Comment: Are you using TC8.x? is "`remote-run`" the name of a remote repo, or part of an actual branch hierarchy?

Comment: As TeamCity describes here (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Branch+Remote+Run+Trigger) I push my commits on Github using "git push origin +HEAD:remote-run/my_feature" command.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Branch Filter** in the **Trigger** and set the only filter as

```
+: remote-run/*
```

Also in **Version Control** under **Branch Specification** use

```
+:( remote-run/*)
```

I also had similar issue and solved it as given above.
I think this would solve your  problem too.